# 404 error tomcat 7 Java Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7, http-status-code-404

So Ive been banging my head against a wall for this.

I followed this tutorial on Tomcat 7 servlets: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKaNotLIGqE

But When I run the servlet I get a 404 error. The video claims what the descriptor file doesnt need the server mappings as tomcat 7 takes care of it.

my servlet:

```
package com.helloworld.servlets;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class HelloWorld
 */
@WebServlet("/HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public HelloWorld() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body><h1>Hello From Chris </body></html>");

    }
```

my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>HellowWorlServlet</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  >
</web-app>
```

Error Message:

HTTP Status 404 - /HellowWorlServlet/HelloWorld

---

type Status report

message /HellowWorlServlet/HelloWorld

description The requested resource is not available.

Appreiciate your thoughts all. Thanks

Comment: are you sure that your application is deployed under /HellowWorlServlet/ root ?

Comment: What's the name of your project?

Comment: The name of the project is HelloWorlServlet, Made a typo when creating it

Comment: With regards to the deployment, How do I go about checking that please?